# laravel dependencies do not work correctly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Help to understand, there is an ordinary model User, with the key role_id:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role', 'id');
    }

    public function isManager()
    {
        return Auth::user()->role->name == 'manager';
    }

    public function isAdmin()
    {
        return Auth::user()->role->name == 'admin';
    }
}
```

And Role model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

migration for users table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')
            ->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->integer('role_id')
            ->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('role_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('roles')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Now the crux of the problem. When I try to get all the managers, only the first one displays the role. Controller:

```
public function managersView()
{
    $role = Role::where('name', 'manager')->first();
    $managers = Role::find($role->id)->users;
    return view('users.managers', [
        'managers' => $managers
    ]);
}
```

View:

```
@foreach ($managers as $manager)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $manager->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $manager->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $manager->role }}</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

The table displays only the role for the first user. Help please understand what is not true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues I see with how your models are set up.

In your user model the foreign key is not set properly. Because the role id exsists on the user it should be a `belongsTo` relation. Also the key should be `role_id`, not `id`. It should look like:

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role', 'role_id');
}
```

Also your role check methods should reference the current model, not the currently authorized user. The way you currently have it `isManager()` will always return the same thing regardless of the user you're calling the method on.

```
public function isManager()
{
    return $this->role->name == 'manager';
}

public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->role->name == 'admin';
}
```

This way you can check the role for any user, not just the current user. If you want to check the role of the current user use `Auth::user()->isAdmin()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should change this line on UsersController:

```
public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role', 'id');
    }
```

to

```
public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role', 'role_id');
    }
```